# Take n elements at a time from a list in RxJava2

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-android, rx-java2

I have a list of elements and I want to process n elements at a time from that list. How can I do it in RX way?

I took a look at `take` operator but that only takes first n or last n elements. I need to process all elements in a list but n at a time.

Ideally I should get multiple lists of size n from a bigger list.

Comment: why not splitting up the list yourself with `subList()`?

Comment: I want to do it in RX way using observables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `window()` (or one of its overloaded variants):

```
observable.window(batchSize).subscribe(...)
```

Or, if you don't want to have to wait for the window to 'fill' then perhaps `buffer()` (or one of its overloaded variants):

```
observable.buffer(batchSize).subscribe(...)
```